Impact of torsional compliance on motor control bandwidth
The stator of my motor is attached to a torsionally compliant body with limited rigidity, and rotor is connected to a gimbal frame. I need to know the impact of this compliance on the maximum disturbance rejection bandwidth that can be achieved by the gimbal. I need to understand the implications of this scenario. What all parameters are needed to evaluate the impact?

Are you talking about mechanical torsion?

Yes. The stator is mounted on a body that has limited torsional stiffness.

What parameters? -- Does this have control system implications or anything? If not, this sounds less like an electronic design problem and more like a mechanical engineering problem.

It sounds like a control problem, which appears in both mechanical (mass, spring) and electrical (inductance, capacitance) systems. They have the same form of equations as they store energy in much the same way as the square of a speed or displacement. Stated as a mechanical problem, you're better off on the mechanical site. If you want to recast it as an equivalent electrical problem, then we can handle it here. Doing the recasting might be a sufficient teddy bear for you to arrive at a solution.
